# How do i make a command so people can place commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command (but i don't know how) that when someone holds a command block renamed Lucky Block it puts them in creative and gets rid of one that they are holding (so if they are holding two it does not get rid of both) and then puts them back into survival if they are not holding it. can be multiple commands if necessary. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a command block for something like that? What if a player places and uses them? Also, what version is this for? The Java edition has seen some severe changes in 1.13 and there is no all-in-one solution.

Comment: I recommend just using any other block for it. There are many "lucky block in Vanilla" systems already, you could look at those, how they did it.

Comment: It seems to me like they would get set to creative, the command block disappears and then they imidiately get set back to survival, because they would no longer be holding it. If they have more than one, then they would be able to have 2 in the hand, they would get set to creative, loose one, and stay in creative for as long as they are holding the other one. Is this how you expect it to work? Do I missunderstand your question?